# First item in an NSMenu does not appear

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I am making my own NSMenu programmatically and popping it up when a button is pressed.

I create NSMenuItems and add them with the NSMenu method `insertItem:atIndex:`.

For some reason whatever item is at position zero in the menu does not show up.  Is this how the menu is supposed to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is how the menu is supposed to work, if the NSPopUpButton `pullsDown`.  The first item corresponds to the title of the button; just insert `""` or whatever you want.  It won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

So you're building your menu in reverse order (by iteratively calling `insertItem:anItem atIndex:0`)?  Why not just build it from the top down and successively call `addItem:`?  I've done this lots and never had issues with items disappearing.